# Intuition for de Rham comparison theorem in $p$-adic Hodge theory

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology, p-adic-hodge-theory

The de Rham comparison theorem from $p$-adic Hodge theory compares the etale cohomology of a variety with the de Rham cohomology of that variety. It says the following:

> Let $K/\mathbf{Q}_p$ be a finite extension, and let $X$ be a smooth
> projective variety over $K$. There is an isomorphism:
> $$H^k_{\text{dR}}(X/K)
>  \otimes_{K} B_{\text{dR}} \cong H^k_{\text{et}}(X_{\overline{K}}, \mathbf{Q}_p) \otimes_{\mathbf{Q}_p} B_{\text{dR}}$$
> which respects the filtrations and $G_K$-actions on both sides. Here $B_{\text{dR}}$ denotes Fontaine's ring of periods.

**My question is**: how is this isomorphism given? That is, given a de Rham cohomology class, how do you produce the corresponding etale cohomology class? Is there some notion of "integration" here that takes in a differential form and produces an etale cohomology class?

Comment: If you want to see how this is related to a notion of “integration” you should look up Colmez integration.

Comment: What would you imagine "producing an etale cohomology class" to mean? Etale classes are kind of hard to write down.